# What am I missing to read content of T4-File?

Tags: c#, t4

I'm in desperate need to generate HTML output with T4 in C#.

I'm using Runtime-T4-Files and chose as option "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor" instead of "TextTemplatingFileGenerator".

My "MyTemplate.tt"-File contains:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

foo
```

My "Program.cs"-File contains:

```
using System;

namespace T4MS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string output = new MyTemplate().TransformText();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing that following error occurs:

Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  CS1069  Der Typname "CompilerErrorCollection" konnte nicht im Namespace "System.CodeDom.Compiler" gefunden werden. Dieser Typ wurde an Assembly "System.CodeDom, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" weitergeleitet. Sie sollten einen Verweis auf die Assembly hinzufügen.  T4MS    C:\Users\figaro\source\repos\T4MS\T4MS\MyTemplate.cs    47  Aktiv

Basically this error tells me to add an assembly reference "System.CodeDom", thrown by my auto generated "MyTemplate.cs"-File.

So I tried to add the "lacking" assembly with `<#@ template language="C#" #> <#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom" #>` or `<#@ assembly name="System.CodeDom" #>`in my tt-File.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to install the `System.CodeDom` NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CodeDom/

Answer (score 0):

This first line works for me.  I can't remember where I read it but in my case it was `langversion` that caused the problem - nothing higher than 7.3 worked but that was a year or two ago

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3" #>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't work out for me. I also tried to look out for other compilerOptions.

Comment: @FigaroHartmann  What version of Visual Studio are you running, what version of .Net, what version/s of C# are supported and what is your reason for not using TextTemplatingFileGenerator?  (My experience based on TextTemplatingFileGenerator.)  It's a good idea to update your question with these details.

Comment: My Visual Studio version is 2019, my .NET version is 3.1. I'm new to C#, so I don't know how to look up my versions, but I'll update them here, as soon as i find them out. Regarding following link i chose run time T4 text templates in order to create HTML output: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019